# Is it possible to change the entire look and feel of JqGrid? (not just theme change)

Tags: jqgrid

I know, this forum has few answers for this question, in below I have the list of answers:

1. Don't load the Jquery UI CSS and JqGrid CSS files and add your own CSS classes to JqGrid

OR

1. Remove CSS classes using JavaScript at runtime and add your own CSS classes to JqGrid.

I am looking for some professional way to change the entire look and feel of the JqGrid.

In my case the first idea will not work out, because I have two grids, I want to change the theme for only one grid, here theme means not just UI theme, the entire look and feel of the JqGrid will be changed.

Comment: What exactly you want change? Could you explain "the entire look and feel of the JqGrid"? Do you want to use two different jQuery UI Theme on one page or you have another problem?

Comment: It is possible to use more than one jQuery UI theme on the same page. But if you want to change the "entire look and feel of the jqGrid" then you need to explain a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load more than one jQuery UI theme on a page. You can do that in this case, and then customize the one theme as much as necessary to change the look and feel of the jqGrid.